# Synchronizing JS actions with JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, onchange

In my JSF page I have a hidden form with an inputText, outputText and submit button. I'm using a script which on certain events fills the inputText and performs a click on the button. The button calls a method in a backing bean in which I need to do some actions and then set the value of the outputText. To do it I find the UIOutput component and set its value. In my javascript I need to perform some other action after the button is clicked but the problem is that it may take some time for the action to be completed and the outputText to be filled with the return value. So the next action in the javascript does not read the correct value. I thought of adding a change event on the outputText so to perform my action only after the value is updated but I have the same problem as this [JS Events: hooking on value change event on text inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847893/js-events-hooking-on-value-change-event-on-text-inputs).

Comment: The button that calls the method in the backing bean is doing an AJAX request?

Comment: Yes it does. It calls the method in the backing bean. The method updates the value of the outputText and the outputText is rendered again with the AJAX request to get the new value.

Comment: Maybe you want to use the `oncomplete` event for the AJAX button, then?

Comment: Are you sure I can do that? I'm using h:commandButton for my button and I don't think it has an onComplete attribute. The AJAX request is an f:ajax child of the button.

Comment: just a sec, I'm posting a complete answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you were using an `a4j:commandButton`, you could just use the `oncomplete` attribute to   some JS code that would execute after completing the AJAX request.

Since you are using a `h:commandButton` with an `f:ajax`, the way to do that is to use the f:ajax attribute `onevent`, and check if it succeeded like this:

```
<script>
    function doWhatever(e){
        if(e.status == 'success'){
            doYourThingHere();
        }
    }
</script>
<h:commandButton action="#{someMB.someAction}">
    <f:ajax ... onevent="doWhatever" />
</h:commandButton>
```

If you use Richfaces, you may want to take a look at `a4j:ajax` component, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590361/is-there-any-difference-between-fajax-and-a4jajax).

**UPDATE:** removed incorrect else that assumed request didn't succeeded. See [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570592/trigger-jsf-ajax-before-javascript/8574487#8574487) to see other meanings for the status attribute.

Comment: The alert message in your `else` is not entirely correct. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570592/trigger-jsf-ajax-before-javascript/8574487#8574487

Comment: @BalusC You're right, I'm going to fix that! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @user579674 You're welcome, I'm glad to help! Please note the update, I've removed the else condition with the alert, cause I was erroneously assuming that the request didn't succeeded.

Comment: The alert was not entirely correct in the else as it was called randomly (I think so) but as a matter of fact I'm still using the else to render a progress bar notifying the user that there is an ongoing action that needs some time and it seems to work as intended.

Comment: @user579674 Please see the answer BalusC linked above (and which I linked in the update too). The status can also be 'begin' (meaning before the request is sent) and 'complete' (meaning after the response is received, but before the DOM is updated -- rerendered)